# Show that a sequence of fields exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I do not have a clue how to solve the following problem:

Let $K\subseteq L$ be Galois extension of degree $p^n$, where $p$ is prime and $n$ is natural. Show that there exists a sequence of subfields $K=K_0 \subseteq K_1 \subseteq K_2 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq K_n \subseteq L$, such that $(K_i : K_{i-1}) = p$, where $i=1, \ldots, n$. Moreover, show $K \subseteq K_i$ is Galois extension.

I will be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is to consider the analogous question involving the corresponding Galois groups.

Comment: Review what you know about nilpotent groups and $p$-groups.

Comment: @angryavian I tried doing it that way  but I have a problem with the second part of a problem, i.e. $K\subseteq K_i$ is the Galois extension

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67108/91741 and the fact that those subgroups are normal.

Comment: @Ragnar I know that there was a fact that if a subgroup of Galois group is normal then some extension is Galois but I cannot find the right formulation of fact.

Comment: Ok, michael. That last comment of yours allows us to identify the missing link. +1 for helping us help you. You seem to have forgotten the following basic fact about Galois theory. Assume that $L/K$ is a Galois, $G$ is the Galois group, and $H\unlhd G$. Let $F$ be the fixed field of $H$. Then we can conclude that $F/K$ is Galois. Also $[L:F]=|H|$ (but this holds even without the assumption about normality of $H$. Combine these with the argument in Rene's (+1) answer.

Comment: Use that a finite p-group has a normal subgroup of index p.

Answer (score 1):

Every $p$ group has a non trivial center, this gives a normal subgroup of order $p$. It corresponds to your $K_n$. And $K_n$ is then Galois, now just continue by induction.

Comment: Could explain the solution in more detail. Why $K \subseteq K_i$ is Galois extension for each $i$.

Comment: Galois subfields correspond to normal subgroups.

Comment: And do you have any easy exokanation for the fact that this subgroup is normal?

Comment: It is a subgroup of the center.